# Transfer overflowed content to another div - jquery

Tags: jquery, overflow

First question on Stack overflow, although I've used for years.

I'm trying to move overflowed content from one slide to the next slide (both are divs) which are placed into a horiztonal scrolling div. I've managed to make a start on this - please see JS fiddle e- http://jsfiddle.net/N7X6W/3/ using the following code

```
count = 0;
$('.slide > .textOnly > .textAlign').each(function() {
var nextSlide = count + 1;
$(this).children('p').each(function() {
    var currentEl = $(this);
    if($(this).is(':in-viewport')) {
        // Do Nothing
    } else {
        $('.slide' + nextSlide + ' > .textOnly > .textAlign').prepend($(this));
    }
});
count++;
});
```

The only problem now is that the content is being moved to the last slide. I assume because it is taking the right and left into consideration.

I'm using this plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.viewport.js and have tried taken out the left and right calculations but with no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, if there is only one slide on screen, then all the second screen's paragraphs ends up on the third.  That doesn't seem to fit any purpose.  What you really care about is **:below-the-fold** (not !:in-viewport), if I understand your intentions correctly.  This is important because it keeps you from retargeting the same items once they are relocated (by definition out of viewport) **unless** it is because they are below the fold on that slide, too.

Once I got that working, there was some detailing.  Paragraphs would still get cut off in the middle.  The question is not just "is P :below-the-fold?", because if the first line is in viewport, then no, P is not below.  What I want to know is if the **whole thing** is in viewport, which since I know the height/width constraints is really "is the last letter of the paragraph in viewport".  Since the last letter is not a smoothly targetable element, I just go ahead and create an empty span at the end of the paragraphs.  Then I ask if **it** is below the fold or not, which tells me if the paragraph was cut off.

```
count = 0;
$('.slide > .textOnly > .textAlign > p').append("<span class='trailer'></span>");
$('.slide > .textOnly > .textAlign').each(function() {
    var nextSlide = $('.slide' + (++count) + ' > .textOnly > .textAlign');
    $($(this).children('p').filter(function() {
        return $(".trailer", this).is(':below-the-fold')
    }).get().reverse())    
      .each(function() { nextSlide.prepend($(this)); });
});
```

Payload:
http://jsfiddle.net/zatz/N7X6W/6/

Note: by iterating through P elements and prepending, you were changing their order! See the use of .reverse().